# Laravel Merge / Replace Request - Files

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5.1

I've been using the `merge()` and `replace()` methods on the `Request` class. It's been working for the most part, but I was under the impression that `merge()` would add or override the existing parameters, while `replace()` wipes out all the parameters and adds the new array of ones passed in. However, they both work how I imagined `merge()` works. Am I missing something here?

Also, is there a way to `merge()` or `replace()` with a file, while still having the `hasFile()` method work? Basically what I'm doing is adapting a request from an API call. So I'm receiving the file in the request as one parameter, and remapping it to another parameter name so it matches what the backend is expecting. After using either method, the request looks correct at a glance when I do a `dd($request->all())`, but `hasfile()` returns false.

I did do some digging into the `Http\Illuminate\Request` class, and I think I'm finding that the issue is my file not being set it `$_FILES`. So it does work as intended I suppose.

With that being said, is there is particular way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

To Answer the first part of your question:

I went directly to the source and confirmed that the functions are indeed different:

*Merge* calls the *add* function which uses [*array_replace* (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php):

```
public function add(array $parameters = array())
{
    $this->parameters = array_replace($this->parameters, $parameters);
}
```

while

*Replace* simply replaces the whole variable(array)

```
public function replace(array $parameters = array())
{
    $this->parameters = $parameters;
}
```

So your initial impression is actually correct.